# Best approach for delayed time password?

Tags: c#, passwords

Here's what I would need my program to do:

a. The program generates some random password and encrypts a file with it.
b. I need to be able to retrieve that password, but not until a day later.

Seems trivial, but there are two requirements:

1. The program must be resistant to windows clock tampering (one shouldn't be able to simply move the clock ahead 1 day, and get the password that way)
2. The program must be resistant to debug tampering (a person with access to source code, shouldn't be able to retrieve the password)

I know I can get time from time server, which would get around requirement #1, but that still leaves requirement #2.  With the source code available, anyone could just modify data received from time server, and fool the application into thinking 1 day has already passed.

Is what I'm trying to do (given the requirements) even possible?

EDIT:
Assume encryption stage IS tamper proof.

To answer one of the questions - the whole point of the application is for a user to be able to hide information from himself for a specific time period (think timed safe where you are not able to open it until a specific time elapses).

Comment: why not store the passwords in a database and retrieve them exclusively from a stored procedure that prevents data being returned unless the time lock requirement has passed?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: I had assumed that the debug tampering requirement involved any part of the code (so would include stored procedures too). If that isn't the case then this could work.

Comment: What is your requirement for this? Perhaps there is another approach that solves your problem?

Comment: The attacker can simply pipe out the plaintext file instead of encrypting it. Nothing you can do about that, apart from creating that file on a trusted system in the first place. Keeping the key secret and thus preventing decryption is possible, keeping the data secret is not.

Comment: Well you could lock down the database permissions so that the application user account can only execute the stored procedure, not select the data.  As long as you can control the permissions, you should be able to do this.

Comment: You could create your own time server that acts as a proxy to some other time server and sign the information coming back from your server.  Only someone on that server with the private key could sign messages so you'd be sure to get correct time (assuming your server doesn't get compromised--which is much harder to do that disassembling code).

Comment: @Chris The application's goal is to hide information from the user for a specific time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it wasn't possible. They key thing it is dependant on time which you have no control over. In theory even trying to get it from a time server is susceptible to a man in the middle attack style since I don't think there is likely to be any encryption on the time checking (though I could be wrong). So without being able to rely on any measurement of time I think you're after the impossible.

Answer (score 2):

If the file generation and encryption routine were tamper proof, the rest of your problem can be solved using a trustworthy server. You can prevent the client from decrypting the file without help from the server, but forcing it to actually encrypt the file and throw away the temporary key is hard.

For example you could encrypt the key and a timestamp with the servers public key, and store it together with the encrypted file. Then the client can't decrypt the file without consulting the server, which will only give it the key once the timestamp is in the past.

Your biggest problem is that the file generation and encryption routine can't be made tamper proof if it runs on an untrusted system. So you need to reconsider your basic design. Probably sacrificing some requirements.

Comment: Assume the generation/encryption routines ARE tamper proof.